# XPath 'following', 'preceding' method equivalent in CSS selecor selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am converting my project element library from xpath to CSS. Some xpath expression written using 'following' and 'preceding' method. Like below.

```
//div[@id='dashboard_right_now']/following::a[contains(@href, 'edit')][text() = 'Posts']
```

Now I want to convert same expression with equivalent CSS. I searched google around and found "+" operator used as 'following' in CSS. But firepath tools gives "no node matched" error.

```
div#dashboard_right_now>div.inside>div>p + a[href*='edit']
```

Any suggestion on how to incorporate 'following' and 'preceding' methods in css selector. Thanks

Comment: css does not allow to navigate back in dom tree, hence there is no corresponding method for ```preceding``` in css. On another note, expression looks very long and prone to errors when application changes.

Comment: Understand, expression bit log. So how about 'following' method? this method also not allowed in CSS?

Comment: Have you tried to change the selectors format, to see if you can get the elements without using the following/preceding? please post html snippets if possible for each case for a more particular answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the following advice:

**preceding:**

- css selector currently does not support traverse backwards, it may be
  supported in the future.

**following:**

- Element E1 following some sibling E2, `css = E2+E1`
- Element E1 following sibling E2 with one element in between, `css = E2+ * + E1`
- Some element immediately following E, `css = E + *`